# How to make a searcher with uncertain number of inputs?

Tags: go, search, struct, slice

I have a structure where I create and store books as follows.

```
type Book struct {
    Authors [] string
    ISBN string
    Countries [] string
    Category string
}

type Books []Book
```

Then I define the values as follows.

```
test123 := Books{}

test123 = append(test123, Book{
        Authors: []string{"Alice", "John", "Bob"},
        Countries: []string{"CA", "US", "DE"},
        ISBN: "1234567",
        Category: "sci-fi",
    })


test123 = append(test123, Book{
        Countries: []string{"UK"},
        Category: "comic book",
        ISBN: "0001298",
    })

test123 = append(test123, Book{
        Authors: []string{"Alice", "Bob"},
        Countries: []string{"UK"},
        Category: "comic book",
        ISBN: "0001298",
    })

test123 = append(test123, Book{
            ISBN: []string{"FR", "AU"},
            Category: "sci-fi",
        })
```

Not every Book structure has all defined elements. So some Book structure elements may not have an ISBN and/or a Countries value.

How can I search in such a structure? For example, I have DE as the Country value and then give Alice as the Author value. How can I write a code that can find and retrieve relevant elements when given the value of both Alice and DE?

**UPDATE**

@Cerise Limón and @gonutz I haven't asked the question exactly, I'm sorry. This code only works for DE and Alice values, not for other values. For other combinations, I have to write blocks of code that consist of if and else. In fact, regardless of the values I will give, I want to make the algorithm that finds values when I search in any slice structure. Is it possible?

Sample Scenario - 1:
I have DE value for Author for Alice Countries. I want to find the "slices" that contain these values in the Books struct.

Sample Scenario - 2:
I have 123456 for ISBN, FR for Countries, Bob for Authors. I want to find the "slices" that contain these values in the Books struct.

In other words, the type and number of values I will give as input can be different.

Comment: I haven't asked the question exactly, I'm sorry. I updated question.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  It will be helpful if you edit the question to show inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Just code up what you want to be able to search for, just `if` and `for` [like this](https://play.golang.org/p/WjGfuspXWjK):

```
for _, b := range books {
    hasDE := false
    for _, c := range b.Countries {
        if c == "DE" {
            hasDE = true
        }
    }

    isAlice := false
    for _, a := range b.Authors {
        if a == "Alice" {
            isAlice = true
        }
    }

    if hasDE && isAlice {
        fmt.Println(b)
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't asked the question exactly, I'm sorry. I updated question.

Comment: Of course you have to add some variables instead of hardcoding your search terms and you must add some more code to handle other cases and combinations. But the spirit is the same as the above.